# Improve the inline image quality in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ide

I am using the Jupyter notebook with Python right now. When I generate an image, one way to get a high-quality image is using

```
plt.savefig('filelocation.png',dpi=900)
```

However, I'm thinking is there a trick that I can improve the inline image quality, so I can just right click this image and 'save as'?

If Jupyter notebook can't make it, is there any other IDE can make it happen? I don't want to save a lot of image files in my folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very easy trick would be to generate a bigger image in your notebook, with a command like this:

```
fig.set_size_inches(30, 30)
```

And with the bigger figure you get a higher resolution!